# PHP MySQLi echo data in array without doing a while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

When using **MySQLi**, do I have to perform a kind of while loop where the actual data from the query is put into a variable array?

```
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// Check if able to connect to database
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error("Database connection failed: "  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";

$rs = $conn->query($sql);
$numRows = $rs->num_rows();
```

I always do the following:

```
$rs->data_seek(0);
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $row['name'];
}

echo $name;
```

Isn't there a much more convenient way to echo the data form the query when there is only one row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is only one row, you don't need the loop. Just do:

```
$row = $rs->fetch_assoc();
$name = $row['name'];
```

Comment: Is it possible to just pick one out the fetch or do one have to fetch all?
Example:
`$name = $rs->fetch_assoc('name');`

Comment: One `fetch` fetches one complete row, not only just one column. But then you can grab only the required columns from its result.

Comment: @Andreas: Nope, it isn't. If you're trying to shorten the code, you can just do `echo $rs->fetch_assoc()['name']` (works on PHP 5.4+). Unrelated: `$numRows = $rs->num_rows();` in your code needs to be `$numRows = $rs->num_rows;`.